# How do I bind an array as a parameter to a prepared statement with an unknown number of variables (Procedural)?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm fairly new to writing programs in PHP, and at the moment, I'm trying to search a database of book titles, based on whether the title contains one word of the search. For example, a search of

> Harry Potter Secrets

Will return the following list in order

> Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (all three words match)
>
> Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone (two words match)
>
> ... (all Harry Potter books)
>
> The Secret Garden (one word match)

I've managed to get this working by typing the SQL directly into the database, but I'm trying to devise a lookup function. However, when I came to bind the parameters, using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, the function only accepts entries in the form:

```
(statement, string types, value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

I've tried:

```
mysqli_prepare($con, “SELECT bookTitle FROM books WHERE bookTitle = ? or bookTitle = ? or bookTitle = ? ….”)

#I can add the repetitions of 'bookTitle = ?' in a for loop


mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( ‘ssss’ , $book_titles)

#Where the number of s' is dynamically added and $book_titles is an array
```

I've noticed that using the object-orientated version allows an array of all values to be passed, but I don't fancy rewriting all of my code again, so I'm going to have to use procedural

My current (hopefully temporary) solution is to not use prepared statements:

```
function search($query) {
    global $con;
            
    $words = preg_split('/\s+/', $query);
    
    $partOne = "SELECT `bookTitle` FROM books WHERE ";
    $partTwo = " ORDER BY ";
    
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $cleanWord = cleanUp($word);
        
        $partOne .= 'LOWER(bookTitle) LIKE "%' . $cleanWord . '%"';
        $partTwo .= "SIGN(LOCATE('" . $cleanWord . "', LOWER(recipeName)))";
        
        if (array_search($word, $words) != count($words) - 1) {
            $partOne .= " OR ";
            $partTwo .= " + ";
        }
    }
    
    $statement = $partOne . $partTwo . " DESC";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $statement);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        #$row["bookTitle"] is the book title
    }
        
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Is there a way of achieving this by using prepared statements instead?

Thank you!

P.S - I've seem other questions answered using the function

> call_user_func_array

But unfortunately, all such solutions seem to use objects, rather than procedural

Comment: Sure there is a duplicate which shows how to do array unpacking `( ‘ssss’ , ...$book_titles)`

Comment: TBH, you want to make the changeover to objects ASAP. A problem such as you’ve just encountered would be a relatively easy fix if you used a wrapper object around your database object. All your code would reference methods of the wrapper and would know nothing about *how* the connection is made to the database. Therefore none of your code would have to be changed; you would just inject a different wrapper in your code.